# Wrap existing memory with const std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, constants

OK, so I recently learned that (a) std::vector uses contiguous memory by definition/standard, and thus (b) &(v[0]) is the address of that contiguous block of memory, which you can read/write to as an old-skool C-array. Like...

```
void printem(size_t n, int* iary)
{ for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) std::cout << iary[i] << std::endl; }
void doublem(size_t n, int* iary)
{ for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) iary[i] *= 2; }

std::vector<int> v;
for (size_t i=0; i<100; ++i) v.push_back(i);
int* iptr = &(v[0]);
doublem(v.size(), iptr);
printem(v.size(), iptr);
```

OK, so that's cool, but I want to go in the other direction. I have lots and lots of existing code like

```
double computeSomething(const std::vector<SomeClass>& v) { ... }
```

If I have a C-array of objects, I can use such code like this:

```
SomeClass cary[100]; // 100*sizeof(SomeClass)
// populate this however
std::vector<SomeClass> v;
for (size_t i=0; i<100; ++i) v.push_back(cary[i]);
// now v is also using 100*sizeof(SomeClass)
double x = computeSomething(v);
```

I would like to do that (a) without the extra space and (b) without the extra time of inserting a redundant copy of all that data into the vector. Note that "just change your stupid computeSomething, idiot" is not sufficient, because there are thousands of such functions/methods that exhibit this pattern that are not under my control and, even if they were are too many to go and change all of them.

Note also that because I am only interested in const std::vector& usage, there is no worry that my original memory will ever need to be resized, or even modified. I would want something like a const std::vector constructor, but I don't know if the language even allows special constructors for const instances of a class, like:

```
namespace std { template <typename T> class vector {
  vector() { ... }
  vector(size_t n) { ... }
  vector(size_t n, const T& t) { ... }
  const vector(size_t n, T*) { ... } // can this be done?
...
```

If that is not possible, how about a container derived off of std::vector called std::const_vector, which (a) could construct from a pointer to a c-array and a size, and (b) purposefully did not implement non-const methods (push_back, resize, etc.), so then even if the object with a typename of const_vector is not actually a const object, the interface which only offers const methods makes it practically const (and any erroneous attempts to modify would be caught at compile time)?

UPDATE: A little messing around shows that this "solves" my problem wrt Windows-implementation of std::vector:

```
template <typename T>
class vector_tweaker : public std::vector<T> {
public:
  vector_tweaker(size_t n, T* t) {
    _saveMyfirst = _Myfirst;
    _saveMylast  = _Mylast;
    _saveMyend   = _Myend;
    _Myfirst = t;
    _Mylast  = t + n;
    _Myend   = t + n;
  }
  ~vector_tweaker() {
    _Myfirst = _saveMyfirst;
    _Mylast  = _saveMylast;
    _Myend   = _saveMyend; // and proceed to std::vector destructor
  }
private:
  T* _saveMyfirst;
  T* _saveMylast;
  T* _saveMyend;
};
```

But of course that "solution" is hideous because (a) it offers no protection against the base class deleting the original memory by doing a resize() or push_back() (except for a careful user that only constructs const vector_tweaker()) -- and (b) it is specific to a particular implementation of std::vector, and would have to be reimplemented for others -- if indeed other platforms only declare their std::vector member data as protected: as microsoft did (seems a Bad Idea).

Comment: Why do you have the C array of objects at all?

Comment: ... changing the function to be more generic IS the right solution.  Now you want to pass an array, but next week it will be `std::array`, and the month after might be `std::deque`.  The "C++ way" has been to pass a pair of iterators, although the experts are now moving toward ranges (which are really just a structure holding a pair of iterators)

Comment: Yes I get the benefits of iterators, but in this case I want contiguous struct { double x,y,z } that I can interpret as a row-major or col-major matrix to send into third-party libraries for matrix multiplication etc, and also send into all these existing functions which take const std::vector<theseobjects>&

Comment: And regardless of iterators being "the C++ way", std::vector offers operator[] (and indeed STL guarantees that vector storage is contiguous) because there are some contexts where this is The Best Way. Given that, why not make the const portion of the std::vector interface available for accessing externally-managed memory?

Comment: @user2387508: You are aware that there's no guarantee that `struct { double x,y,z }` is contiguous? Better have a huge `double[]` and an a shim class with appropriate `{double* base; double getX(); }`.

Comment: Subscripting is available through iterators (random access iterators, anyway)

Comment: No, you are **not** supposed to change the vector from the `data` pointer or `&v[0]`.

Comment: I was dubious about that myself; I put a check in there, comparing the addresses of a few elements to their sizeof() to guarantee contiguity, and if that check fails then I take the step of copying all the data out. But if the standard guarantees contiguity, and the vector is const, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try reference-logic storing introduced in C++11  with `std::reference_wrapper<>`:

```
SomeClass cary[100];
// ...
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<SomeClass>> cv;
cv.push_back(cary[i]);   // no object copying is done, reference wrapper is stored
```

Or without C11, you can create a specialization of such template class for bytes - char. Then for the constructor from `char*` C-array you can use `::memcpy`: which unfortunately will then use twice as much memory.

```
::memcpy(&v[0], c_arr, n);
```

Something like this:

```
template <typename T> class MyVector : public std::vector<T> {
};

template <> class MyVector<char> : public std::vector<char> {
    public:
    MyVector<char>(char* carr, size_t n) : std::vector<char>(n) {
        ::memcpy(&operator[](0), carr, n);
    }
};
```

What I would recommend - replace all C-arrays to vectors where possible, then no extra copying will be needed.

Comment: Be careful that if the objects are not trivially copyable, the behavior of memcpy is undefined.

Comment: Yes I am aware that I can copy c_arr into std::vector more efficiently than my example, but that doesnt' change the fact that twice as much memory, redundantly holding the same bytes, must be used. What I want is to not copy data at all, but to wrap a const std::vector around existing memory.

Comment: Specializing `std::vector<char>` would be undefined behavior.  Specializations within namespace std need to involve user-defined types in some way, and `char` isn't.

Comment: @user2387508 STL containers copy elements by default, you cannot change this logic. Can you replace C-arrays to vectors from the very beginning? The code which works with C-arrays should work with vectors. Then there will be no extra memory copying.

Comment: "STL containers copy elements by default" why? 
"you cannot change this logic" why not? It would be very useful to avoid duplicating memory and wrap up an existing c-array with the const parts of the std::vector interface.

Comment: @BenVoigt I meant specialization of own inherited class, like in my code sample.

Comment: " you cannot change logic of copying elements to the std::vector, it is the logic of all STL containers by design." -- what is the justification of this design decision, that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @user2387508 in C++11 such possibility was introduced - look at the post. But be careful with time live of source objects - if they will be deleted, container references will point to deallocated memory.

Comment: @user2387508 at this post - my answer to the question above, I've edited it.
Use `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<SomeClass>> cv;`

Comment: That reference_wrapper looks very interesting. Unfortunately, my company is extremely conservative with its IT policies, so I am stuck with Visual Studio 2008. Maybe in another 5-10 years I will get to use C++11 !

Comment: this strikes me as dangerous, since I can only assume that `size()` and `data()` will not work as expected